# Unit testing a function that logs out a user from inactivity

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-jasmine

Using Angular/Jasmine/Karma I am testing a function that runs in ngOnInit that will log out a user from 15 minutes inactivity.

Here is the original code:

```
   #setSessionTimeout() {
      const clicks$ = fromEvent(document, 'click');
      const checkInterval = 60000; // 1 minute
      const timeLimit = 15; // 15 minutes
  
      clicks$.pipe(
        startWith('fake click'),
        switchMap(() =>
          interval(checkInterval).pipe(
            tap(value => {                                    
              console.log(value);                                                        
              if (value > timeLimit) {                                                   
                this.router.navigate(['logout']);                            
              }                                                              
            })
          )                                                                  
        )                                                                    
      ).subscribe()                                                          
    }
```

Here is my test:

```js
    fit('should log out a user after 15 minutes of inactivity', fakeAsync(() => {                                    
      tick(1000 * 60 * 60 * 60);                                                                                                                      
      fixture.detectChanges();                                                                                                                                                       
      expect(routerMock.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['logout']);                                                                  
    }));
```

I can not get the test to pass. It also looks like that function is not running in the test because I see no console.log out. How can I test this function properly?

Comment: please provide a testing stackblitz for quick resolution [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bjdbyf-dslzgm)

Comment: you're right, deleted my answer, do share a stackblitz for testing possible solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answered**:

Ok, I figure it out. I had a `fixture.detectChanges();` in the beforeEach() hook which was placed there by angular's cli when it created the test. If I move that `fixture.detectChanges();` out of the beforeEach() and place it in the tests instead, then I can successfully test my logic successfully.

It does not make sense because there is still `fixture.detectChanges();` that is called initially per a test, just in the test itself instead of the beforeEach(). Nevertheless, it was the issue and solution.

It should be noted that `#setSessionTimeout()` is called in ngOnInit() which complicates the testing situation. If it was a public function that I could test without ngOnInit() kicking it off, it would of not required this workaround.

Here are my tests which I successfully verified no false positives or vice versa:

```js
it('should log out a user after 15 minutes of inactivity', fakeAsync(() => {                                                                             
      fixture.detectChanges();                                                                                                                 

      tick(1000 * 60 * 15); // reaches 14 times                                                                                                                
      fixture.detectChanges();                                                                                                                      

      tick(1000 * 60 * 15); // reaches 29 times and logs out                                                                                                                                             
      fixture.detectChanges();                                                                                        
                                                                                                                               
      expect(routerMock.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['logout']);                                                                                                    
      discardPeriodicTasks();
    }));                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                    
    it('should not log out a user after 15 minutes of inactivity because user did a click', fakeAsync(() => {
      fixture.detectChanges();                                                                                                                   

      tick(1000 * 60 * 15); // reaches 14 times                                                                                                  
      fixture.detectChanges();                                                                                                                   
                                                                                                                                                                                                      
      document.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'));                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                 
      tick(1000 * 60 * 15); // reaches 29 and does not logout because of click                                                                                                   
      fixture.detectChanges();
                                                                                                                                              
      expect(routerMock.navigate).not.toHaveBeenCalledWith(['logout']);                                                                    
      discardPeriodicTasks();
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want runs ngOnInit, you can do like this and this works!

```js
fit('should log out a user after 15 minutes of inactivity', async () => {                                    
  component.ngOnInit();
  fixture.detectChanges();                                                                                                                                                       
  await fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
     expect(routerMock.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['logout']);
  })                                                                  
});
```

Comment: I need to use tick() to control the test